# Загрузка файла в процентах

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Нужно создать `label` с процентами загрузки файла от 0 до 100 использую этот код.

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.progressView setProgress:totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated:YES];
}
```

Пытался создать, но этот код не работает - в тексте `label` получаю (null)

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten  totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%", (int)(totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite)*100];


        _label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(91, 15, 500, 50)];
        [_label setText: percentage];
        _label.numberOfLines = 1;
        _label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [self.view addSubview:_label];


        });  

}
```

Как создать `label` с процентами загрузки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", (int)(((double)totalBytesWritten/(double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)*100)];
```

Comment: Теперь 0% и дальше не идет

Comment: а totalBytesWritten меняется?

Comment: Да,  totalBytesWritten меняется

Comment: можете попробовать вывести в консоль percentage и посмотреть меняется ли он

Comment: Как именно нужно вывести в консоль?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", percentage);

Comment: Какую секунду пишет 0% когда загрузка завершена пишет 100%

Comment: тогда попробуйте вывести totalBytesWritten и totalBytesExpectedToWrite

Comment: не заметил, что это интеджеры. исправил ответ

Comment: Сделал totalBytesWritten и totalBytesExpectedToWrite float и вывел их в percentage. работает